# How do i sort the datetime from oldest to newest, excluding all the duplicate words in python from textfile

Tags: python-3.x, list, datetime, timestamp, text-files

here is my textfile:

```
['hello', 'sffr', '18/08/2019 21:36:43', '1']

['bye', 'asadf', '19/08/2019 18:23:15', '1']

['bye', 'asadf', '19/08/2019 19:53:15', '2']

['bye', 'sdfsd', '23/08/2019 15:40:24', '3']

['flower', 'hellooooo', '23/08/2019 15:41:37', '1']

['hello', 'hlekfhdfld', '23/08/2019 15:41:45', '2']

['flower', 'dfgdfg', '23/08/2019 15:41:59', '2']

['pot', 'sdf', '23/08/2019 15:45:14', '1']
```

I want to sort my data from oldest to newest by the datetime and exclude all the duplicate words. For each word, i want to take the latest timing.

The below are the codes i have done, i only managed to take out the datetime from the file by word but i can't get the latest timing and sort the whole data from oldest to newest.

```
import csv

word = input('\nAdd a word: ')

sorted_dates = []
with open('history.txt', 'r') as readFile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(readFile, delimiter=',', quotechar="'")

    for i, line in enumerate(csvreader, 1):
        if not line:
            continue
        if word in line[0]:
            sorted_dates = line[2]
            print(sorted_dates)
```

here is my timestamp code:

```
timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

expected output would be:

```
['bye', 'sdfsd', '23/08/2019 15:40:24', '3']

['hello', 'hlekfhdfld', '23/08/2019 15:41:45', '2']

['flower', 'dfgdfg', '23/08/2019 15:41:59', '2']

['pot', 'sdf', '23/08/2019 15:45:14', '1']
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need.

```
data = [['hello', 'sffr', '18/08/2019 21:36:43', '1'],
['bye', 'asadf', '19/08/2019 18:23:15', '1'],
['bye', 'asadf', '19/08/2019 19:53:15', '2'],
['bye', 'sdfsd', '23/08/2019 15:40:24', '3'],
['flower', 'hellooooo', '23/08/2019 15:41:37', '1'],
['hello', 'hlekfhdfld', '23/08/2019 15:41:45', '2'],
['flower', 'dfgdfg', '23/08/2019 15:41:59', '2'],
['pot', 'sdf', '23/08/2019 15:45:14', '1']]

seen = set()
result = []
for i in sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True):
    if i[0] not in seen:
        result.append(i)
        seen.add(i[0])

print(sorted(result, key=lambda x: x[2]))
```

**Output:**

```
[['bye', 'sdfsd', '23/08/2019 15:40:24', '3'],
 ['hello', 'hlekfhdfld', '23/08/2019 15:41:45', '2'],
 ['flower', 'dfgdfg', '23/08/2019 15:41:59', '2'],
 ['pot', 'sdf', '23/08/2019 15:45:14', '1']]
```

---

To read data

```
import ast
data = []
with open('history.txt', 'r') as readFile:
    for line in readFile:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            data.append(ast.literal_eval(line.strip()))
```

Comment: is it possible to retrieve the data from a text file that i have provided instead of typing it on python itself? i am using this line of codes to retrieve:

```
                    with open('history.txt', 'r') as readFile:
                        csvreader = csv.reader(readFile, delimiter=',', quotechar="'")

                        for i, line in enumerate(csvreader, 1):
                            if not line:
                                continue
```

Comment: hi please help me @rakesh

Comment: Updated snippet